# Reducing score on Solr for specific categories

Tags: solr, filtering

I'm searching for products in my catalog using Solr.
I'm trying to give a lower score for products from category "Books" but with no success.
I also tried to filter results from "Books" category, but i still get them, so I figured that i'm doing something wrong.
The categories field is indexed.

this is one try (out of many other tries) of a request that i made:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/query?q=iphone+4s&rows=4&fq=price:[*+TO+500]&debugQuery=on&fq=not(query(category:Books))
```

I also tried using bf parameter with a negative impact on "Books" and still with no luck.

What should I do to reduce the score when I have "Books" and other categories? and how do I filter results with a specific Category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to append the following code to your request :-

```
&bq=(*:* -category:Books)^1000000
```

the number 1000000 specifies a very large number which will boost those records where the category is not Books.

So, your code becomes :-

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/query?q=iphone+4s&rows=4&fq=price:[*+TO+500]&debugQuery=on&bq=(*:* -category:Books)^1000000
```

for filtering results with a specific category, append the following code to your request:-

```
&fq=category:Books
```

The above will show all records where category is Books.

to get all records where category is not Books, try the following :-

```
&fq=(*:* -category:Books)
```

Comment: thanks! works great! how can I do it for multiple categories? not books and no magazines? simply bq=(*:* -category:Books OR Magazines )^1000000

Comment: you will have to add multiple bq parameters for that.

&bq=(*:* -category:Books)^100000&bq=(*:* -category:Magazines)^1000000